# Brand cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

How I can solve this problem.
If the Brand should be class then, why? What is the concept behind this error?

[[image: Dear Senoir's Please explain this error]]]

```
package abstraction;

public class RepairShop {

    public void repairCar(WagonR car) {

    }
    public void repairCar(Brand car) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }

}
```

Comment: The concept of the error is pretty much what the compiler error says: "*`Brand` cannot be resolved*". The type `Brand` is not known, thus one has to declare it (as cass, enum or interface). Did you, by any means, meant `String car` instead of `Brand car`?

Comment: What do you expect `Brand` to be?

Comment: If `Brand` is supposed to be a type, then you need to write or import a type called `Brand`. Just _wanting_ it to be a type doesn't make it exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Brand object?

```
public class Brand{
 private String name;
public void setBrand(String brand){
this.brand = brand
}
public String getBrand(){
return this.brand;
}
}
```

Comment: When I Create Brand Class then Error goes remove, But confusing is that , I want to know concept explanation , i'm terms and conditions , when and how I should do this.Please Reply.

Comment: Well WagonR and Brand are java objects / classes and without the existence of those objects the compiler or IDE will complain. That's like asking for a ball to play with without the other person having a ball to give. And in the object oriented world of Java, Brand in this case is an object. Similar to RepairShop.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You are saying *"Hey Java, use this `Brand` class I created"*. But looking at your project layout, there is no `Brand` class.

You probably forgot to create it.

---

### Solution

Just create the class in your project, like you already did with `RepairShop`, `Audi` and `WagonR`. Maybe something like this:

```
public class Brand {
    private final String name;

    public Brand(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I do not really know what you want your `Brand` to do or contain. So feel free to adjust it to your needs.

---

### Notes

#### Inheritance

In case you intended to be able to pass `Audi` to this method, which wants `Brand`, you probably also want to use inheritance. So

```
public class Audi extends Brand { ... }
```

#### Encapsulation

Note that encapsulation might be better suited for this type of architecture. Maybe with `Brand` being an **enum**:

```
public enum Brand {
    AUDI,
    BMW,
    PORSCHE,
    ...
}
```

And then dropping the `Audi` class. A `Car` then has a property `Brand`, like:

```
public class Car {
    private final Brand brand;
    ...

    public Car(Brand brand, ...) {
        this.brand = brand;
        ...
    }

    public Brand getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    ...
}
```

Calling it like:

```
Car car = new Car(Brand.AUDI, ...);
```

Comment: absolutely, when i create Brand class then Error goes remove, But confusing is that why we need to create Brand class ? I'm mean, what topic is related to that concept.or if you want to suggest any video for better understanding, Please drop link, I'm waiting your precious Reply.

Comment: It is impossible to use a class without creating it. How should Java know what a `Brand` is if you dont tell it what it is by creating it? That is very fundamental.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer solved your question, feel free to **accept** it, thanks.